# Receiving email with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I was looking for some good way to parse mails with rails 3.2.

I did not want to setup external server as R. Bates show in episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/313-receiving-email-with-mailman

I found simple solution:

```
  Mail.defaults do
  retriever_method :pop3, :address    => "pop.gmail.com",
    :port       => 995,
    :user_name  => '*****@gmail.com',
    :password   => '*****',
    :enable_ssl => true
  end

  Mail.all.each do |email|
    some_email_parser(email)
  end
```

It is fired up as rake task invoked by Cron every 15min.
If you see any disadvantages of that approach let me know.

Comment: Anyway.. You are going in right way.. go-ahead.

Comment: Code is working. My question was if you do it any other way and as well share my idea of resolving a problem. I do not understad what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine so I leave it like this.